# iPhone simulator is stuck on splash screen after build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm currently attempting to run an app with CocoaPods. I first run `npm start -- --reset-cache` in the app root. While this runs in the background, I open the workspace in Xcode and run the build.

The simulator will open and the app will launch, showing the splash screen. While this happens, the terminal that ran `npm start -- --reset-cache` will run the BUNDLE.

Once the BUNDLE is done running, this will be the result:

```
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░ 93.8% (1133/1170)::1 - - [27/Oct/2018:18:11:53 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "TEO/1 CFNetwork/901.1 Darwin/17.7.0"
BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1170/1170), done.
```

But the app will stay at the splash screen:

[image: State of the simulator]

## Steps to reproduce

- run `npm start -- --reset-cache` in terminal
- open ios workspace in xcode and `Cmd-R`
- wait for bundle to finish running in terminal

## Expected behavior

Simulator will open, wait for bundle to finish and then run

## Actual behavior

Simulator will run, bundle will finish but app stays at splash screen. cannot reload or close app.

-

I've tried cleaning and building multiple times but to no avail

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you saying that there's some sort of incompatibility between `npm`, which is a Javascript package manager, and Xcode generally? Or do you think there's a problem with your particular project? You haven't told us anything at all about the project, and AFAIK Xcode and the simulator don't have a lot to do with Javascript. Despite your "steps to reproduce," I don't think anyone could reproduce your situation without more information.

Comment: hello you ever fixed this issue, i am facing same...i tried creating new app several times but always app stuck at splash screen only.....if resolved please provide solution....i am using all latest versions